# How do I click a specific part of a single item in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-cursoradapter

Every item in my GridView is a custom layout consisting of four ImageViews, each with their own ids, each of which has its image set by a custom CursorAdapter.

I'd like to have clicking each of the ImageViews in an item lead to a different function. I'd also like to have the id of the GridView item to be used in the function.

If I use gridview.setOnItemClickListener, it looks for clicks to the item as a whole. If I use android:onClick in the XML, it doesn't give me the id of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `getView` method of custom adapter, set `OnClickListener` for each `ImageView`.

```
imageView1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    imageView2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

imageView1.setOnClickListener(...
imageView2.setOnClickListener(...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this click the item as a whole, instead of a specific part?

Comment: I think I'd worded this a a little ambiguously, earlier, sorry

Comment: This mostly worked! Is there any way to get the id here, instead of the position?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: You can get Id from Gridview position.

Like. 

YourOBj yourObj=yourArraylist.get(position);

String id=yourObj.getId();

Comment: And what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
your_grid_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // this will toast your clicked item position.
   }
});
```